# Disentangle php from html

Tags: php, refactoring, php-7.2, automated-refactoring

I have been given a nightmarish Wordpress theme written in this style:

```
<?php } if (isset($excerpt) && $excerpt != '') { ?> 
  <h3 class="box-caption <?php echo $color; ?>" blah <? echo "foobar"...
```

which has several problems under php 7.2. It needs to be fixed and taken to a maintainable state.

The only hope I can see is to reduce it to pure php, by disentangling the html via echo() statements so it can be fixed and refactored. Going at it by hand is hardly feasible, so I am looking for tools that would do this task, but google is not helping - looks like I should write one.

Advice?

Comment: you have to write it your own, but why php 7.2 will give issue if it's already working?  means which kind of issue you are talking about? any example?

Comment: One case that was done by hand had an "unexpected endwhile;" (it occasionally uses while..endwhile. May God have mercy of him/her 'cuz I don't). After refactoring the problem went away (with no apparent change in block structure) and moved to the next file in the chain. But there are user issues, like echo()ing WP functions that already echo() when invoked. Etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.